# Python asyncio, aioamqp callbacks and pytest

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pytest, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write some tests for some asynchronous Python code using the aioamqp message broker, but pytest and callbacks fail me.

Simply put, when the aioamqp basic_consume() function receives a message and calls the assigned asynchronous callback, inside the callback I can do whatever I like -- reference unassigned variables, assert something outrageous -- and pytest happily passes the test. Clearly an exception gets raised under the hood and the test is interrupted, since the callback function never runs further than the first failing line, but the failure never rises all the way to pytest.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate:

```
import aioamqp
import asyncio
import pytest


MQ_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
MQ_PORT = 5672
MQ_LOGIN = 'login'
MQ_PASSWORD = 'password'


class MockMQ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.transport = None
        self.protocol = None

    async def connect(self):
        try:
            self.transport, self.protocol = await aioamqp.connect(
                host=MQ_HOST, port=MQ_PORT, login=MQ_LOGIN, password=MQ_PASSWORD
            )
            self.channel = await self.protocol.channel()
        except aioamqp.AmqpClosedConnection:
            print('closed connection')
            return

    async def close(self):
        await self.protocol.close()
        self.transport.close()

    async def publish(self, data, queue_name, exchange='', properties=None):
        queue = await self.channel.queue_declare(queue_name)
        await self.channel.publish(data, exchange, queue_name, properties=properties)

    async def consume(self, callback, queue_name):
        await self.channel.basic_consume(callback, queue_name=queue_name)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_mq():
    """Basic ping-pong test for RabbitMQ."""
    QUEUE_NAME = 'my_queue'

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def callback(channel, body, envelope, properties):
        """This is the callback called when a MQ message is consumed."""
        print('we are here')
        await channel.basic_client_ack(envelope.delivery_tag)
        print(body)     # this gets printed as well
        foo = bar * 2   # this is where we fail
        assert body == b'bar'
        print('we never arrive here')

    mq = MockMQ()
    await mq.connect()
    await mq.consume(callback, QUEUE_NAME)
    await mq.publish(b'foo', QUEUE_NAME)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await mq.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test_mq())
```

Running this via the main program with IPython results correctly in an exception, since it doesn't get swallowed by pytest.

What is the proper way of writing tests for pytest in this case? pytest-asyncio does not seem to affect this issue in the least.

EDIT: I might as well add that my dev environment uses Django and pytest-django, but removing it doesn't change the result either.

Comment: You’re only supposed to decorate your tests. What happens if you remove the decorator from `callback`?

Comment: That's just a relic from my incessant shotgun debugging with and without pytest-asyncio. It doesn't affect the result one bit.

Comment: Have you solved this? Facing a similar thing now..